# Expansion of $\frac{1}{ \sin x} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

How is

$$\csc x = \dfrac{1}{t} + \sum\limits_{k= 1}^{+ \infty} (-1)^k \Big( \dfrac{1}{t + kπ} + \dfrac{1}{t - kπ} \Big) $$

Where $x = k \pi ± t$

I saw this in one of the proofs and I'm not sure how? It says it is the partial fraction form of $\csc x $

Comment: The difference between csc x and the expansion has no poles in the complex plane, so it's an analytic function. You can show that this function is bounded, and then apply [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))

Comment: You may also apply $\frac{d}{dx}\log(\ldots)$ to both sides of $$\sin(x)=x\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right)$$ which is the Weierstrass product for the sine function.

Answer (score 4):

We begin by expanding the function $\cos(ax)$ in a Fourier series,

$$\cos(xy)=a_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(nx) \tag1$$

for $x\in [-\pi/\pi]$.  The Fourier coefficients are given by

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(xy)\cos(nx)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1\pi (-1)^n \sin(\pi y)\left(\frac{1}{y +n}+\frac{1}{y -n}\right)\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$, setting $x=0$, and dividing by $\sin(\pi y)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\pi \csc(\pi y)&=\frac1y +\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{y -n}+\frac{1}{y +n}\right) \tag 3
\end{align}$$

Dividing by $\pi$ and setting $y=t/\pi$  yields

$$\csc(t)=\frac1{t} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{t -n\pi}+\frac{1}{t +n\pi }\right)$$